# Camel with Elastic search version issue unsupported version: [2.0.0]

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel, elasticsearch-plugin, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to hit remote elastic search cluster from my camel client project and getting the error as "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]".  Please find the code snippet.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch</artifactId>  
  <version>2.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

blueprint.xml

```
<route id="timerToLog">
        <from uri="timer:foo?period=5000" />
        <setBody>
            <method ref="helloBean" method="hello" />
        </setBody>          
        <to uri="elasticsearch://test-poc?ip=127.0.01&amp;port=9300&amp;operation=INDEX&amp;indexName=testindex&amp;indexType=sampletxn" />         
    </route>
```

Error log from node:-

```
    [2017-01-09T18:04:14,887][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [127.0.01] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x5c33c900, L:/127.0.01:9300 - R:/10.132.245.194:64393]], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1236) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:396) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:536) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:490) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) [netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

Can anyone suggest please how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a bit of an educated guess but I actually just came across the same exact issue with the same versions for both.  I believe it's a version mismatch inherent to camel 2.18.1 and the latest version of elasticsearch.  I downloaded the sources for the camel-elasticsearch and looked in the top level pom and saw this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>${elasticsearch-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The variable `elasticsearch-version` is set to 2.3.5 in the parent pom (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.18.x/parent/pom.xml) so it stands to reason it would fail with this message.

Unfortunately, it looks like we'll either have to adapt to using some kind of elasticsearch API for 5.x or downgrading elasticsearch.  It's pretty unfortunate.

Edit:  And it looks like it's now set to 2.4.3 (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/8c434ef27742aa85d1763b1c3d4ab4fe9d8428a6/parent/pom.xml) in the latest commit so we may have to wait a bit for them to catch up.  2.4 is the latest version before 5.x according to their docs (what a weird numbering system?) so it might not be too long, maybe even next release, but I won't be holding my breath.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and now i am clear about this camel elastic search version mismatch.  Finally I decided to go with Transport client instead of this.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using the elasticsearch Java API, myself, and calling it within a bean from camel.  I'm not sure if that's the best way to go or not but at least it should work.